# jQuery form submit() is not working in IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I want to submit a  with using jquery as below;

```
$("#formid").submit();
```

Its working perfect in all browsers except IE6.

How to make it work in IE6 ??

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You probably have an `<input name="submit" />` somewhere in your form, which overwrites the function "submit" of the form in IE.

**Edit:**

I have tested in some other browsers. The latest versions of all major browsers seem to be affected by this issue.

- IE - all versions
- Firefox 4+
- Chrome at least since version 12
- Opera at least since version 11

Bottom line: Never name your inputs "submit", or any other default property or method of the form element (e.g. "action" or "reset") . See [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement) for a complete overview.

Comment: Yups. I have an input tag (button) name as "submit" and that was creating problem. Thanks!

Comment: Wow nice catch. Was not aware of this.

Comment: Extremely useful bit of info. Probably saved me an hour of troubleshooting. NOTE: This is not restricted to IE6.

Comment: I noticed this problem using Firefox 4 as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also had the problem for days now in ff4. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: This resolution also works in IE7.  The initial problem does not happen in IE8, or IE9.

Comment: Amazing! Didn't expect this. I'm sure glad for this post.

Comment: @KristoferHoch I noticed that misbehaviour in IE8, too.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem when I was about to submit the form via an A-element. I had set the href attribute to "javascript:;" to let the main jQuery script handle the actual submit but it just wouldn't work in IE6.

jQuery main script:

```
$(".submitLink").click(function(){
$(this).parent()[0].submit();
$(this).addClass("loading");
});
```

My solution was to change the href attribute from "javascript:;" to "#".

Comment: Excellent, in my case I set the href to "javascript:void(0);".  All events hooked into click() fired, but the form would not submit.  Changing the href to "#" fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem as Peter, fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $(".submitLink").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // prevent browser from scrolling to top of page
});

Answer (score 3):

You could try `$("#formid").trigger("submit")`, though I doubt it'll give you a different result.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had a similar issue, where I was creating a "pseudo-form" within an ASP.NET server form (so I couldn't use another form tag), which I wanted to post to another domain without needing to write server-side code to do the remote post. Easy answer - create a form on the fly and submit it. Works in good browsers...

After some trials and tribulations, I realised that IE won't work as expected (what a surprise) unless the form that is being submitted has been added to DOM. So, this was my solution. I hope it helps some of you. Please be aware, all of my inputs and my submit were in the same container. ".post-to" is a hidden input with the URL.

```
$(".post-form").click(function(ev) {

    var postto = $(this).siblings(".post-to").val();    
    var form = document.createElement("form")
    $(form).attr("id", "reg-form").attr("name", "reg-form").attr("action", postto).attr("method", "post").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

    $(this).siblings("input:text").each(function() {
        $(form).append($(this).clone());
    });

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);

    return false;
});
```

Eventually, it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to return false; if you're on an  tag

Answer (score 0):

Add a `button` in your form with `type="submit"`

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/submit/#comment-55074466).

Answer (score -1):

```
...

$('.bt_ok').bind('click', function() {
    $('#form_autosuggest').submit();
    return false;
});

...
```

Add after: `return false;` for IE6

Answer (score -1):

Just add a

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $("#formid").submit();
}, 300);
```

Comment: Why I received a -1? Here the "setTimeout" solution works perfectly.