# jQuery is not submitting form values with .submit()

Tags: jquery

I have a form with `action = post` and i am validating it with after validating it I am submitting that form with:

```
$("#form").submit();
```

But it is submitting all fields nulled while I have data in those fields. How can I post those fields filled?

Comment: post your code so that it can be troubleshooted.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Is there a right answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with "trigger", though I doubt it'll give you a different result:

```
$(form).trigger("submit");
```

But I think the real solution, is to put the validation inside the submit method, in this way:

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
      if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
        $("span").text("Validated...").show();
        return true;
      }
      $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
      return false;
    });
```

Look here to (if the problem is with ie6):

[jQuery form submit() is not working in IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445850/jquery-form-submit-is-not-working-in-ie6)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, found out that my input was without the name attribute, that is required for post data.

Answer (score 0):

Does your form have an id set to "form"? If not just remove the hash from your $("#form")..sorry to be cheeky but there is no code so I am guessing...

Answer (score 0):

submit JQuery method don't send the form, it

> Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element

You have to use the "standard" submit method.