# Jquery form.submit not posting anything in IE9

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've been seraching for a solution on my problem for several days, but I haven't found a solutiuon that solves my problem. I hope someone here might be able to help me out or to point me in the right direction.
My problem is the following:
I'm using jquery (1.9.0) and jquery-ui (1.10.1). I have a page with a form, which should be posted to a php-script to add or update data into my database. All works fine in FF and even in IE 8 and IE 10. But in IE9 the data just isn't submitted: var_dump'ing the $_POST-array gives me an empty array, nothing is posted.

Here is the code (I'll submit the essentials:

```php
    <form name="documents" id="documents" method="POST" action="inc/add_new_doc.php">
        <table class="invoer" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" colspan="8"><h2>Please fill out all fields</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Originator:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><select name="company_id" id ="company_id"><?php echo getCompanyList(0); ?></select></td>
            <td>Originator document number:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="docnrsupplier" id="docnrsupplier" type="text" size="30" tabindex="2" /></td>
            <td>Document category:</td>
            <td><select name="doccat_id" id ="doccat_id"><?php echo getDocCatList(0); ?></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>LAB GmbH</b></td>
            <td>LAB document number:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="docnrlab" id="docnrlab" type="text" size="30" tabindex="2" /></td>
            <td>Document size:</td>
            <td><select name="docsize_id" id ="docsize_id"><?php echo getDocSizeList(0); ?></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Client:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>CEH</b></td>
            <td>Client document number:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="docnrclient" id="docnrclient" type="text" size="30" tabindex="2" /></td>
            <td>Current revision:</td>
            <td><select name="revi" id ="revi"><?php echo buildAZSelector(); ?></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Title (line 1):</td>
            <td colspan="5"><input name="title1" id="title1" type="text" size="100" tabindex="2" /></td>
            <td>Current doc. phase:</td>
            <td><select name="docphase_id" id ="docphase_id"><?php echo getDocPhaseList(0); ?></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Title (line 2):</td>
            <td colspan="5"><input name="title2" id="title2" type="text" size="100" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Title (line 3):</td>
            <td colspan="5"><input name="title3" id="title3" type="text" size="100" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Title (line 4):</td>
            <td colspan="5"><input name="title4" id="title4" type="text" size="100" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">File formats:</td>
            <td align="right"><i>editable:</i></td>
            <td ><select name="docformat_editable_id" id ="docformat_editable_id"><?php echo getDocFormatList(0, 1); ?></select></td>
            <td align="right">Filename:</td>
            <td colspan="4" align="left"><input name="file_editable" id="file_editable" type="text" size="50" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"></td>
            <td align="right"><i>non-editable:</i></td>
            <td ><select name="docformat_noneditable_id" id ="docformat_noneditable_id"><?php echo getDocFormatList(0, 0); ?></select></td>
            <td align="right">Filename:</td>
            <td colspan="4" align="left"><input name="file_noneditable" id="file_noneditable" type="text" size="50" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="8">
            <div class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="submitNewDoc" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Submit</span>
            </div>
            <div class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="cancelNewDoc" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

The jquery for the Submit-button:

```js
    $( "#submitNewDoc" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#documents" ).submit();
        });
```

When I test in FF and in IE8 or IE10, the data gets posted just fine. Only in IE9 the data is not being posted, I receive "array{}".

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

** update in reply to Muhammed's question **

There's nothing in the php-file except the MySQL-query:

```php
    // All general includes
    require_once('config.php');
    require_once('functions.general.php');
    require_once('functions.dbase.php');
    //require_once("standardLists.php");

    // make a connection, so we can use mysql_real_escape_string
    $con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }


    // Initialise database object and establish a connection
    // at the same time - db_user / db_password / db_name / db_host
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql($db_user,$db_password,$db_name,$db_host);

    var_dump($_POST); // testing

    /* Storing the info into the DB */

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO documents 
                    (company_id, docnrsupplier, docnrlab, docnrclient, title1, title2, title3, 
                    title4, docformat_editable_id, docformat_noneditable_id, file_editable, doccat_id, docsize_id, docphase_id, file_noneditable)
                    VALUES (
                            '".$_POST['company_id']."',
                            '".$_POST['docnrsupplier']."', 
                            '".$_POST['docnrlab']."', 
                            '".$_POST['docnrclient']."', 
                            '".$_POST['title1']."', 
                            '".$_POST['title2']."' , 
                            '".$_POST['title3']."',
                            '".$_POST['title4']."', 
                            '".$_POST['docformat_editable_id']."', 
                            '".$_POST['docformat_noneditable_id']."', 
                            '".$_POST['file_editable']."' , 
                            '".$_POST['doccat_id']."' , 
                            '".$_POST['docsize_id']."' , 
                            '".$_POST['docphase_id']."' , 
                            '".$_POST['file_noneditable']."')";
```

** update 2 **

I have tried it now with bothtypes of button, but the result in IE9 stays the same: `array(0) { }` while IE8 and IE10 at least give me

array(16) { ["company_id"]=> string(0) "" ["docnrsupplier"]=> string(0) "" ["doccat_id"]=> string(0) "" ["docnrlab"]=> string(0) "" ["docsize_id"]=> string(0) "" ["docnrclient"]=> string(0) "" ["revi"]=> string(1) "A" ["title1"]=> string(0) "" ["docphase_id"]=> string(0) "" ["title2"]=> string(0) "" ["title3"]=> string(0) "" ["title4"]=> string(0) "" ["docformat_editable_id"]=> string(0) "" ["file_editable"]=> string(0) "" ["docformat_noneditable_id"]=> string(0) "" ["file_noneditable"]=> string(0) "" } `

```php
    <input class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <div class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="submitNewDoc" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Submit</span>
    </div>
```

I'm sure I have made a mistake, I just cannot find it :-(
Can it be that there is a problem with having two forms on the same page? They do have their own name and id and there are no double fieldnames..

Comment: Can you add relevant part of PHP file?

Comment: There's nothing in there except the MySQL-query:

Comment: You are not using real buttons? Why? Talk about killing accessibility.

Comment: Are you using the full, real versions of each IE browser, or some testing tool?

Comment: @epascarello I have tried using `<input name="submit" />` but that doesn't fire the "submit"-event either. I tried an alternative name to avoid a name/id like "submit", but that didn't work either. An similar issue I read [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445850/jquery-form-submit-is-not-working-in-ie6), although that is about IE6

Comment: @j08691 I tried at work the real IE9, where I discovered the problem. At home I am using IE10 in browsermodus IE9, which has the same result. I don't know how I can install two versions of IE on one machine btw.

Comment: http://ietester.en.softonic.com/

Comment: @Sheikh Heera what is the difference between this tool and the built-in developer-tool in IE10?

Comment: This will let you check any page in IE `5 t0 9` which is basically not possible in a single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found it, although I am quite unhappy with it:
The form-fields were nested as inside a table:
`<form><table><tr><td><input...>` as you can see in my original question.

After searching on SO further I read sth about issues with a table within a form inside a jquery accordion. Just for trying I removed all html concerning the table, so now I have sth like `<accordion> -> <form> -> <input ....>`

And that works! So, for some reason the nesting I did must have hit a bug in IE9.

It looks awful, but it works. It's for internal use anyway, so it'll have to do.

I hope this may help others, who met this issue too.